# IIDentity does not contain a definition for 'GetUserId'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the VS2015 MVC controller and specifically GetUserID on User.Identity

i have seen a number of similar questions relating to this which state to add reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, however as you can see that is referenced.

i assume i'm missing a package or something i just cannot figure it out

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Web_Test.Models;  

namespace Web_Test.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
    public TestController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; private set; }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //GetUserId() underlined in Red in VS2015
        //IIDentity does not contain a definition for 'GetUserId'
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is authentication mode set to "forms"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to add `using System.Security.Principal;`, since the extension method is part of that namespace. See the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/626362d8a22625e82a2af1b7076796f161510a97/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/ClaimsIdentityExtensions.cs#L6).

Answer (score 13):

Adding the following worked for me. I also needed to add the NuGet Package [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/) mentioned by [@Badri.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392883/5301903)

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; // NuGet: Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core.
```